# Sharepoint Designer 2010: Is it possible to customize the field types under "Collect Data From User" in the WF

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I'm trying something that should be included in the default SPD behavior but is not: in the workflow, on the Collect Data from User Action, I would like to be able to upload files to the list.  Out of the box, SPD 2010 only supports basic types, lookups, and hyperlinks.  Is there a way to customize SPD to include Upload File type?

Digging a little deeper into \14\TEMPLATE\1033\Workflow\WSS.Actions, we see that the "Collect User Data" uses the Survey template for data collection.  Does that mean that we have to modify/create a new template? or do we have to create a new column type?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

It will not be possible just extending the "Collect Data from User" action with your custom column types (or different column types than already offered).

You will have to create your own "Collect Data from User" action and include an upload functionality like that. Some pointers to get you started creating your own Sharepoint Designer Workflow Actions:

- [Adding Custom Actions in SharePoint Designer 2010](http://blog.furuknap.net/adding-custom-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010)
- [Extending SharePoint Designer Workflow with Custom Actions](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/extending-sharepoint-designer-workflow-with-custom-actions.aspx)